# Camel Processor for an endpoint

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am experimenting with Camel and finding it a convenient tool for endpoint integration.  I've set up the following experimental application:

The first endpoint is a simple http-get request (using curl on the command line).  This interfaces with a central switch using Jetty (this is the Camel-based app).  This does some elementary tinkering and passes the request to another endpoint (a Thrift server) which handles the request. Its reponse is then routed back to the command-line client. The set up is therefore a kind of tier-3 over-engineered Hello-world architecture.

My routes typically takes this form:

```
from("jetty:http://localhost:8080/hello").process(new DummyProcessor()).process(new HelloProcessor());
```

My question is as follows:

Given that the HelloProcessor sends a Thrift message to another endpoint to process, shouldn't this rather be a Component?  Is it good (acceptable) practise to use a Processor for such a task?  Furthermore, what are the advantages for writing a component if it is indeed acceptable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are not really any benefits in writing a component if you are going to use it in one or a few routes.

If you intend to use this processor in multiple routes in the future, and you need a way to configure it by some parameters - then you typically write your own component. It also perhaps makes the route more readable. A component is also an easy artifact to share between different Camel applications and projects.

```
from("file:///var/files/inbox").to("http://www.example.com/");
vs
from("file:///var/files/inbox").process(sendHttpToExampleDotComProcessor); // or whatever
```

If it's a one time use - don't overcomplicate.